# Can I find an arcade more than once during a playthrough?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

In Binding of Isaac, can I find an arcade more than one time during my playthrough? For example, if I find an arcade during one of the Cave levels, can I find another one later in Depths?

Comment: Not sure, but nothing in the Wiki says you can't, and they usually note stuff like that when it's known http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Arcade

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes

In my experience, you can find more than one arcade room per play through. I once had 3 in a row! As mentioned before, the wiki doesn't say it can't happen.

Comment: I confirm also; I've encountered the arcade multiple times in one playthrough, from the Basement up through the Womb.